# Invalid solver name

Tags: matlab

I have the neural network toolbox. However, I am getting error 'invalid solver name' when I tried to use 'adam' and 'rmsprop', but when I used 'sgdm', it is working. I tried to do help ___, but it is not showing other solver name except for sgdm.
Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have an old version of Matlab.

Back in 2016, SGDM was the only choice you had to train your network. Newer versions of have additional possibilities, including Adam (the method was first published in 2015, introduced in 2018a, see [trainingOptions](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainingoptions.html)).

---

You can always search the old docs to observe the evolution of some particular function;  https://de.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html

**R2017b**
[image]

**R2018a**
[image]

Comment: I have matlab r2017b